# Why is my palindrome detector not working(returning only one input)?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to practice Ruby, and am making a palindrome detector.

I have tried changing the `else` to `elsif` but neither worked.

```
print "Enter a Word and check if it's a Palindrome!"
word = gets.chomp
if word.reverse! == word
  print "The word you entered was a Palindrome!"
else  
  print "The word is not a Palindrome!"
end
```

It only returns `"The word you entered was a Palindrome!"` but it should be returning one or the other.

Comment: Remove the bang `!` after `reverse`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the bang `!` because [String#reverse!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-reverse-21) reverses the string in place and the condition is always true.

This is what is happening:

```
word = "whathever"
word.reverse!
#=> "revehtahw"

word
#=> "revehtahw"

"revehtahw" == "revehtahw"
#=> true
```

This is what you need:

```
word = "whathever"
word.reverse
#=> "revehtahw"

word
#=> "whathever"

"revehtahw" == "whathever"
#=> false
```

Comment: The fact that `reverse!` is in-place is not really the relevant bit. In fact, it is actually mostly irrelevant what `reverse!` does. The salient bit is that it returns `self`, in other words, it returns the object `word` points to.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, thank you for pointing it for a deeper understanding. Which leads to the difference between `==` and [equal?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-eql-3F)

Comment: Since `reverse!` returns `self`, there wouldn't be any difference between `==` and `equal?`.

Answer (score 2):

[`String#reverse!` returns `self`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-reverse-21), i.e. the object the `reverse!` message was sent to. So, in other words, `word.reverse!` returns the object referenced to by `word`, which is always equal to itself, ergo

```
word.reverse! == word
```

is always `true`.

What you are looking for is [`String#reverse`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-reverse), which returns *a new string*.

Comment: Interesting that – unlike most other `!` methods in `String` – this one doesn't return `nil` if the receiver already happens to be a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said, you need to remove the `!` operator as `str.reverse!`manipulates the string in-place.

If you're new to Ruby, some cool things you can also do are put code before if statements to make it more readable and shorten it. Also, the ternary operator `(?:)` is useful as well.

**Code Before If Example**

```
print "Enter a Word and check if it's a Palindrome!"
word = gets.chomp

print "The word you entered was a Palindrome!" if word.reverse == word
print "The word is not a Palindrome!" if word.reverse != word
```

**Ternary Example**

```
print "Enter a Word and check if it's a Palindrome!"
word = gets.chomp

puts word.reverse == word ? "It's a Palindrome!" : "It's not a Palindrome!"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add a "!" to a method (like you have with word.reverse!) ruby takes it to mean change the original permanently so word would become word.reverse. So when you compare word.reverse! to word, you have already changed word to be the reverse so every word you put in came back as true.

What you need to change is

```
if word.reverse == word
```

this will actually check if the current word is equal to the reversed word.